# Postgres cost of large volume of inserts in many tables in a single transaction

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

What is the additional cost incurred by inserting large volume or rows (millions), in many tables in a single transaction ?

Can something be done (tuning parameters) so that the cost of inserting in large volume in a single transaction approaches the cost of doing it in autocommit ?

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure what your limit is or what your concern is but millions of rows is not a problem. Billions of rows isn't a really a problem either. The larger the transaction the better for performance. Transactions have overhead.

Here on my old x230 I

1. create a table with a million rows.
2. add a million rows.
3. add a BILLION rows. Damn. That's a lot of rowzzz.

Here is the code and results.

```
test=# CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT id::bigint FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS gs(id);
SELECT 1000000
Time: 722.075 ms
test=# INSERT INTO foo SELECT id FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS gs(id);
INSERT 0 1000000
Time: 1285.631 ms
test=# INSERT INTO foo SELECT id FROM generate_series(1,1e9) AS gs(id);
INSERT 0 1000000000
Time: 2142933.903 ms
```

So you can see, you can do a million rows in a second or a billion in 35 minutes.

If you're asking why the bigger batch was slower, I think that's the overhead of WAL which would eventually show to be even greater if I did them in smaller batches (I think).

The maximum transaction size is like 2-4 billion, but just to not be excessive I would cut it off at a 2 billion rows per transaction.

Comment: Yeah the cost of checkpoints over time add up. A million rows might fit in before a checkpoint gets kicked off etc.

Comment: So, I was correct then, there is a size beyond which performance declines

Comment: @Gaius no, you weren't correct. I hit a checkpoint: *"yeah the cost of checkpoints over time add up. A million rows might fit in before a checkpoint gets kicked off etc."*

Comment: Your own experiment shows "the bigger batch was slower"

Comment: It's more like performance averages out. You won't go faster with more smaller transactions. If you're loading data over a long haul, like hours of inserts, then the difference between inserting 1,000,000 rows 1,000 times and inserting 1,000 rows 1,000,000 times will be negligable.

Answer (score 4):

You have it backwards - it is generally better to do many rows in a single transaction than one at a time with autocommit. The reasons are a) disk I/O and b) network round trips between client and server. You will need to run benchmarks to find the ideal batch size for your data and your hardware - try 100, 1000, 10000 sized transactions and see. At some point it will peak and past that the transactions will be "too big" as you bump into some other limit.

Comment: *"At some point it will peak and past that the transactions will be "too big" as you bump into some other limit."* I'm not sure about that. I can't think of any such limit that would indicate that this statement is true in PostgreSQL.

Comment: You mean postgres will not for example run out of memory and start swapping when handling a transaction processing too much data? That is interesting as idea - sadly it goes against basics of physics. There is always a limit where things are peaking. For example, it may take too long to send the data for the transaction - it may simply be more efficient to send smaller batches.

Comment: Yep that is indeed what I meant - the OP hasn't provided any details about the actual size in bytes nor their hardware or postgresql.conf. So it will need to be determined experimentally

Comment: PostgreSQL, afaik, materializes the rows on disk. At the end of the transaction those rows are made live or left dead. It doesn't hold all of the rows in memory. And, why would it? So essentially if you commit one at a time, they're placed on the table and made active right away. If you commit them all at once, they're placed on the table and made active later (or left dead when you rollback). @TomTom

Comment: And what work is the PG doing in the meantime for MVCC and anything else? It may well be that a single billion-row transaction is faster than 1000 million-row transactions but noone can say for this specific workload without doing some experiments.

Comment: PG is writing things to the disks, not holding them in memory. Only a toy database would try to hold a whole transaction in memory.

Comment: I am not sure what we are arguing about here. You cannot do an unlimited size transaction in Postgres or any other database. There is insufficient information available about the OPs workload, system and configuration to say what the "best" transaction size would be to maximise throughput, hence the need to experiment.

Comment: I assert that bigger transaction sizes are better up to a peak, then decline.

Comment: "*And what work is the PG doing in the meantime for MVCC and anything else?*" - that work is **not** done in memory. The MVCC information is stored along with the data in the table blocks. Large transactions do not eat up memory - especially not inserts (updates that need to hold lock information do in fact require some memory)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the internet as some years has past since this question raised:

I just did an actual migration project to using PG12 as the target. The DB was sufficiently large to draw some conclusions:

The entire database was:

- ~300 mio rows
- ~300 tables
- ~30 mio rows / table max
- ~22 GB SQL text
- ~30 Gb final size on disk.

It was committed as one big transaction, using "COPY stdin". It was executed ~25 minutes on my laptop. The insert speed was pretty stable over the time. It seems that it had more dependency on the type of data rather than time passed/transaction size, commit was instant. (I'll try to make a graph to be more concrete)